# Can there exist any element with an 8th principal shell?

Tags: electrons, orbitals, atoms

I am a high school student. While studying the atomic structure a question appeared to me. We know that an atom can have the highest limit of 7 Bohr energy shells or principal energy shells, respectively labelled K,L,M,N,O,P,Q. Can any element that contains more than 7 energy shells exist? Equivalently, does there exist any element that has an 8th energy shell (which would presumably be the R shell)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_periodic_table

Comment: I would like to add that there will likely be an answer soon as réactions for element 119, or ununennium, are currently being attempted. Although no definite success was seen, the new element will be the first member of the 8th period and will be an alkali metal. Because of this, it will probably be the new largest element as well, although it’s radioactivity will most probably not topple cesium from being the largest atomic radius.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is certainly possible, and in fact very likely. Nuclear physics predicts an island of stable elements around an atomic number of 120 [$^{[1]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability), with the two heavier of the three elements predicted to be most stable having an $\ce{8s^2}$[$^{[2]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbinilium) and an $\ce{8s^2 8p^1}$[$^{[3]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbihexium) configuration, respectively.

Comment: Then that would be another milestone in the history of chemistry. Thank you for the help.